How to get a value from a cell based on another cell google sheets
I've a cell for example A1 that its content is, let's say =B1 that resolves to a dummy string. From A1 I want to extract the "B" value (the column) from the =B1 formula (not the text that is resolved), is there a way to do this?

You can use FORMULATEXT:
=REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A1),"[A-Z]+")


Steady solution.
